# Handle Azure AD authentication in offline

Tags: c#, .net-core

Called Microsoft's azure ad api to get the configuration in the below code snippet,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Instance = AzureADDetail.AuthenticationEndpoint;
                    options.Domain = ServerAppConfig.IdaTenant;
                    options.TenantId = "common";
                });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                    JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme);

                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
                    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
            });
}
```

During offline startup some API requests are failing, so changed like below and removed AddAuthentication of azure authentication,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
       var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
              JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
              defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
       defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
              options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
       });
}
```

How to make the first sample to work in both online (network connected) and offline (network disconnected) of the machine during startup of c# api application in .netcore?

Comment: Authorizing without Authentication is not a good idea. Please research AAA, without proper logging(Auditing data), your application would fail every aspect of basic security design principles.

Comment: The only answer is to use a locally cached Authenticator with credentials already cached, within the timeout period for Offline access, or setup a local AD controller to mirror the off site AD and provide local authentication during offline periods.